# If an error occurs in my stored procedure, will a cursor local to that procedure get cleaned up?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, cursor

In a stored procedure, I have the following cursor:

```
DECLARE @cur CURSOR
SET @cur = CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY
FOR     SELECT  -- various columns
        FROM    @localTableVariable
```

...and then I open it, iterate, and close it. (Yes, I have a reason for iterating rather than doing set operations.)

If an error occurs, will that cursor get closed/cleaned up? I don't see anything about that in, say, [the MSDN page on `CLOSE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175035.aspx). Or do I need to implement a `TRY`/`CATCH` and close it in the stored procedure code? (And then `RAISEERROR` to allow the error to allow the error to propagate to our usual error handling.)

I figure the answer *has* to be "yes, it'll get cleaned up," but...

Would the answer be the same if the cursor were for a real table rather than a table variable?

(This is within an explicit transaction where the procedure has `SET XACT_ABORT ON`, if that's relevant. *Edit:* And it appears that for my specific use case, I can be sure it'll get closed by using [`SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT ON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184746.aspx), because my transaction will be committed or rolled back by the end of my stored procedure. But I'm curious about the general case.)

Comment: If you are still sceptical use this to check if there are active cursors `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_cursors(0) WHERE name = 'your_cursor_name'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [the very useful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26994212/if-an-error-occurs-in-my-stored-procedure-will-a-cursor-local-to-that-procedure#comment42519673_26994212) from [SubqueryCrunch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3593875/subquerycrunch), I've empirically proved that the cursor gets cleaned up (without all the transaction stuff), at least on SQL Server 2012 with the options we're using:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE tjtemp
AS
BEGIN
        DECLARE @foo TABLE
        (
                id INT
        )
        DECLARE @id INT

        INSERT INTO @foo (id)
        VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6)

        DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY
        FOR SELECT id FROM @foo
        OPEN cur

        SELECT 'inside' AS Label, * FROM sys.dm_exec_cursors(0) WHERE name = 'cur'

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @id
        WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
        BEGIN
                PRINT @id
                IF @id = 4
                        RAISERROR(N'ack!', 18, 1);

                FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @id
        END
        CLOSE cur
END
GO
SELECT 'before' AS Label, * FROM sys.dm_exec_cursors(0) WHERE name = 'cur'
GO
EXEC tjtemp
GO
SELECT 'after' AS Label, * FROM sys.dm_exec_cursors(0) WHERE name = 'cur'
GO
```

(That's with a named cursor rather than a cursor variable, but see below.)

Results:

[image]

Messages:

```
(0 row(s) affected)

(6 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
1
2
3
4
Msg 50000, Level 18, State 1, Procedure tjtemp, Line 24
ack!

(0 row(s) affected)
```

We can see that the cursor doesn't exist before the procedure is started, exists when the procedure has it open, and doesn't exist after the procedure has terminated with an error.

I'd prefer finding something in the docs, but this supports the "surely it has to work that way" gut feeling.

It turns out that with a cursor variable, the `name` column in `dm_exec_cursors` gets the variable's name, so I was able to prove it for the variable as well:

```
DROP PROCEDURE tjtemp
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE tjtemp
AS
BEGIN
        DECLARE @foo TABLE
        (
                id INT
        )
        DECLARE @id INT
        DECLARE @cur CURSOR

        INSERT INTO @foo (id)
        VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6)

        SET @cur = CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY
        FOR SELECT id FROM @foo
        OPEN @cur

        SELECT 'inside' AS Label, * FROM sys.dm_exec_cursors(0) WHERE name = '@cur'

        FETCH NEXT FROM @cur INTO @id
        WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
        BEGIN
                PRINT @id
                IF @id = 4
                        RAISERROR(N'ack!', 18, 1);

                FETCH NEXT FROM @cur INTO @id
        END
        CLOSE @cur
END
GO
SELECT 'before' AS Label, * FROM sys.dm_exec_cursors(0) WHERE name = '@cur'
GO
EXEC tjtemp
GO
SELECT 'after' AS Label, * FROM sys.dm_exec_cursors(0) WHERE name = '@cur'
GO
```

(Same results.)

But I also did a run without any `WHERE` clause on the selects from `dm_exec_cursors` (when no one else was doing anything on the DB), just to be sure.